# Formula to update a number field on the same day of every month

Tags: formula

I need to add a certain number of minutes to a number field on the same day every month, i.e., on the 14th day of every month.  The 14th Day is being pulled from the closedate field on the Opportunity Object.  So, I need to add 120 to custom field Minutes_Available__c (Opportunity Object) on the 14th day of every month, as pulled from the closedate

I'm a Salesforce novice and I'm having trouble.

Comment: Can you provide a real example and more details? what is used for? for what records (any validations)?

Comment: do you mean, that when the 14th of the month rolls around, you want to add 120 to `minutes_available__c`? If yes, you'll need a time-based workflow or scheduled job so when that day rolls around, a DML action can occur

Comment: what do you mean by 14th day as pulled from close date?  If today is 14th then make the update?  or if CloseDate is 14th (of any month)?

Comment: we have a support plan that adds 120 minutes every month for a client to use.  We do not pro-rate to the beginning of the month.  Some of the plans allow for roll-over minutes and some do not.  So the number of minutes will either reset to 120 every month or it will be 120 minutes + the number of minutes left from the previous month.

Comment: Cheryl, are you still looking for a solution? @sfdcFanBoy has a good point and I could add more details to have it working for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a scheduled batch class like the below code and schedule it to run everyday.

```
    global class BatchUpdateMinutes implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable{ 

    global Database.Querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC ){  
        //gets all opportunity with CloseDate as 14th.
        //Also change this criteria as per your needs            
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity Where DAY_IN_MONTH(CloseDate) = 14]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> oppList )
    {
       //loop through opp list and update fields as per your needs
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```